# Specifying function parameter type, but not variable

Tags: c++, function, parameters, c++11

I have seen example code like this before

```
class C
{
    C();
    ~C();
    foo(T1, T2);
}

C::foo(T1, T2)
{
    //not using T1/T2
}
```

versus conventional code like this

```
class D
{
    D();
    ~D();
    bar(T1 t1, T2 t2);
}

D::bar(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    //using t1 and t2
}
```

And I am wondering what is the purpose of not defining your type variables for usability? Do most people do this just to hint that those parameters of the api are not currently in use, but to ensure backward compatibility in the future?

Is it possibly for RTTI, or referencing static variables (although the various samples I've seen were not using it for this purpose, they werent even templated functions, the variables were simply unused). I've tried searching for this feature but I am not even sure what it is called or what to search.

Basically, what are the reasons/benefits/downsides for using this approach?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771492/c-style-convention-parameter-names-within-class-declaration

Comment: Maybe as a way to make compiler not warn of unused parameters... Not good idea, IMHO, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is commonly done to suppress compiler warnings about unused variables. When you do not create a variable name, the compiler will not warn you that the variable is not being used in the function.

Like you stated, its usually that parameters are not being used for the particular implementation:

```
class an_iface
{
public:
    an_iface();

    virtual int doSomething(int valNeeded)=0;
}

#define NOT_SUPPORTED -1
class something : public an_iface
{
public:
    something();
    int doSomething (int) { return NOT_SUPPORTED; }
}

class somethingMore : public an_iface
{
public:
    somethingMore();
    int doSomething(int stuff) { return stuff * 10; }
}
```

Comment: So basically, there is absolutely no reason to use this semantic if you are not using it in some polymorphic fashion? I'll accept this if there are no other reasons or better use cases.

Comment: No reason I can think of. Wouldn't make any sense for another purpose. It could be any type of interface. Qt signals and slots come to mind, where an object may emit a signal with 2 parameters but a receiving slot in certain objects may only care about one of them.

Comment: Acceptable answer then, dbrank0 also touched on the same idea of suppressing compiler warnings... although I agree it's probably not a good idea. Also doesn't make your intent entirely clear.

Comment: yeah, class designs where child classes dont offer all functionality described by the parent interface or usually bad design (your example). The parent interface should be split into multiple interfaces, so the child classes can inherit from those interfaces they actually DO implement, so that the liskov substitution principle wont get violated.

Comment: Just mentioning, I agree with dbrank0 and smerlin that this is not a good design. The example is provided simply to describe a case where one might find this. Unfortunately most of us are not lucky enough to get to work on only fresh, well designed software :) I am not advocating designing an interface like this!

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what @dag has mentioned, a function definition without parameter name finds its usage in template specialization. I know you have mentioned that there are no templates in the example you have posted, but for sake of completeness i'd like to post this use case:

Suppose you have defined an `erase` function for `std` containers. But you want different `erase_helper` to do the actual work based on the container type. A common and acceptable practice is to use `traits`.

```
// Tags for containers
struct vector_tag {};
struct map_tag {};

// Trait class
template <typename C> struct container_traits;

// Specialization of trait class
template <typename T, typename A>
  struct container_traits<std::vector<T, A>>
  {
    typedef vector_tag category;
  };

template <typename K, typename V, typename C, typename A>
  struct container_traits<std::map<K, V, C, A>>
  {
    typedef map_tag category;
  };

// Helper function
template <typename Container, typename X>
  void erase_helper(Container& c, const X& x, vector_tag)  // <-- no param name
  {
    // Erase element from vector
  }

template <typename Container, typename X>
  void erase_helper(Container& c, const X& x, map_tag)  // <-- no param name
  {
    // Erase element from map
  }

// Function interface
template <typename Container, typename X>
  void erase(Container& c, const X& x)
  {
    erase_helper(c, x, typename container_traits<Container>::category());
  }
```

You can see here, `erase_helper` has third parameter without a name. Type of parameter tells compiler to pick correct function at template instantiation phase.

Comment: To be fair, this is still polymorphic usage.  You're just doing your polymorphism at compile time instead of run time.

Comment: @Managu, yes it is. But original question was not asking for all use cases except polymorphic usage :-).

Answer (score 3):

Parameters are designed before the implements in more cases which affected by the architecture more directly

Parameters may be unused because:

1. Overload a virtual function which has more parameters than needed in derived class
2. Parameters exist for history reason, and don't want to change the api yet
3. Consider for the need of the future

Comment: Very good second point. In big projects you can't just go and break the API whenever you feel like it, so it's best to comment out obsolete parameters until a release is scheduled.