# Creating generic print function from templates to print values of the variable of primitive data types

Tags: c++

As the question suggests I am trying to create a pretty straightforward generic print function that tries to wrap `std::cout` (poorly!). Below is the code that I have written. But when I try to use it to print the value of variable `x` seems like it is giving me the dynamically allocated ____ (I don't really know what to put there so please feel free to fill that gap as well!) My question is that can someone please explain this behavior that why this is not working the way it should?

```
template <typename T>
void printValueOf(T)
{
    T t;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = 12;
    printValueOf(x);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is t initialized?

Comment: No, what should it be initialized to? @JVApen

Comment: @Jash you need the parameter to be passed, check my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled your compiler warnings? With `Wall` flag in GCC for example, I got:

```
In function 'void printValueOf(T) [with T = int]':
warning: 't' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
|     std::cout << t << std::endl;
         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Change your function to this:

```
template <typename T>
void printValueOf(T t)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

where you expect a typename of type `T`, a parameter named `t` of type `T`, and eventually you print `t`.

In your posted function, you ignored the parameter, by providing only its type, and then, you were creating a new, local variable named `t`. You didn't initialize the variable `t`, and then you print it, thus the compiler warning.

However, you don't want to create a new local variable, you want to print the passed parameter.

---

A bit advanced for beginners, but the reason your code could compile was: [Specifying function parameter type, but not variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494056/specifying-function-parameter-type-but-not-variable).

Comment: wow, can you point me to the details/docs beneath this?  I will accept the answer as soon as SO will let me to do so. lol thanks btw!

Comment: I updated my answer @Jash, hope that helps, cheers! You can google around for functions, parameters and templates, if you feel like it.

Comment: That totally makes sense. thanks for dumbing it down. lol. I sure will. Seems like it's going to be once heck of a ride learning `C++`. ;)